# Issue while converting JSON to List of Objects

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to convert JSON file to C# list of Objects. However I encounter a problem while converting the JSON file.

My attempt:

```
List<Root> array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);
```

Error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Root]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path '50010', line 1, position 9.'

Json Data:

```
{
    "50010": {
        "name": "..Undefined person..",
        "isInProduction": 0,
        "total_hours": 175.89,
        "total_overjob_hours": 0,
        "total_days": 21,
        "total_vacation": 0,
        "total_sick": 0,
        "total_work_Sunday": 0,
        "total_work_Saturday": 2,
        "total_shift_Adm": 0,
        "total_shift_1": 7,
        "total_shift_2": 9,
        "total_shift_3": 5,
        "day_02": {
            "comment": "13:43-22:08\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.4,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_03": {
            "comment": "13:43-22:05\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.38,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_04": {
            "comment": "13:44-22:06\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.36,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_05": {
            "comment": "13:43-22:05\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.38,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_08": {
            "comment": "05:41-14:06\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.42,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_09": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:08\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.43,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_10": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:07\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.41,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_11": {
            "comment": "05:41-14:06\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.42,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_12": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:09\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.45,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_13": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:07\r\nSaturday job; Shift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.41,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_15": {
            "comment": "21:48-06:06\r\nShift:3; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 3
        },
        "day_16": {
            "comment": "21:43-06:06\r\nShift:3; ",
            "hours": 8.38,
            "shift": 3
        },
        "day_17": {
            "comment": "21:46-06:09\r\nShift:3; ",
            "hours": 8.38,
            "shift": 3
        },
        "day_18": {
            "comment": "21:42-06:05\r\nShift:3; ",
            "hours": 8.38,
            "shift": 3
        },
        "day_19": {
            "comment": "21:48-06:05\r\nShift:3; ",
            "hours": 8.29,
            "shift": 3
        },
        "day_22": {
            "comment": "13:47-22:07\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.33,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_23": {
            "comment": "13:47-22:07\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.32,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_25": {
            "comment": "13:47-22:07\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.34,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_26": {
            "comment": "13:44-22:06\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.37,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_27": {
            "comment": "13:46-22:07\r\nSaturday job; Shift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.35,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_29": {
            "comment": "05:44-14:08\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.39,
            "shift": 1
        }
    },
    "50011": {
        "name": "..Undefined person..",
        "isInProduction": 0,
        "total_hours": 174.8,
        "total_overjob_hours": 0,
        "total_days": 21,
        "total_vacation": 0,
        "total_sick": 0,
        "total_work_Sunday": 0,
        "total_work_Saturday": 1,
        "total_shift_Adm": 0,
        "total_shift_1": 20,
        "total_shift_2": 1,
        "total_shift_3": 0,
        "day_02": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_03": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:02\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.32,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_04": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_05": {
            "comment": "05:44-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.29,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_08": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:02\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.34,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_09": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.32,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_10": {
            "comment": "05:44-14:02\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.29,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_11": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:02\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.35,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_12": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:03\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.33,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_15": {
            "comment": "05:44-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.29,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_16": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.31,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_17": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_18": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_19": {
            "comment": "05:43-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.3,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_22": {
            "comment": "05:38-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.37,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_23": {
            "comment": "05:42-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.32,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_24": {
            "comment": "13:39-22:03\r\nShift:2; ",
            "hours": 8.39,
            "shift": 2
        },
        "day_25": {
            "comment": "05:40-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.36,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_26": {
            "comment": "05:41-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.33,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_27": {
            "comment": "05:41-14:01\r\nSaturday job; Shift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.34,
            "shift": 1
        },
        "day_29": {
            "comment": "05:40-14:01\r\nShift:1; ",
            "hours": 8.35,
            "shift": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not an array, but is an object.

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Root>>(json);` instead.

Comment: Yong Shun, indeed is not array. I'm expecting list of objects. array is just random variablename at the moment.

Comment: how does your Root object looks like?

Comment: @phuzi I don't think that is working. I got key "50010" and value {ConsoleApp1.Root}. I'm not sure I can't reach other properties from Root

Comment: It's fixed the error you were getting. Now we need to know the class definition of `Root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    Dictionary<string, Data> data = jObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>();

    foreach (var item in jObj.Properties())
    {
        var days = data[item.Name].days = new();
        foreach (var prop in ((JObject)item.Value).Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object) continue;
            var day = prop.Value.ToObject<Day>();
            day.day = prop.Name;
            days.Add(day);
        }
    }

public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int isInProduction { get; set; }
    public double total_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_overjob_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_days { get; set; }
    public int total_vacation { get; set; }
    public int total_sick { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Sunday { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Saturday { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_Adm { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_1 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_2 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_3 { get; set; }
    public List<Day> days { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}
```

or maybe it makes sense use a second dictionary instead of a list

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    //... another properties
    public Dictionary<string,Day> days { get; set; }
}

//...another code
    if (prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object) continue;
    days.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToObject<Day>());
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are understanding incorrectly what is happening. The json it self is an object. So the expected code would be:

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

objects looking like this:

```
public class _50010
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int isInProduction { get; set; }
    public double total_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_overjob_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_days { get; set; }
    public int total_vacation { get; set; }
    public int total_sick { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Sunday { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Saturday { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_Adm { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_1 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_2 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_3 { get; set; }
    public Day02 day_02 { get; set; }
    public Day03 day_03 { get; set; }
    public Day04 day_04 { get; set; }
    public Day05 day_05 { get; set; }
    public Day08 day_08 { get; set; }
    public Day09 day_09 { get; set; }
    public Day10 day_10 { get; set; }
    public Day11 day_11 { get; set; }
    public Day12 day_12 { get; set; }
    public Day13 day_13 { get; set; }
    public Day15 day_15 { get; set; }
    public Day16 day_16 { get; set; }
    public Day17 day_17 { get; set; }
    public Day18 day_18 { get; set; }
    public Day19 day_19 { get; set; }
    public Day22 day_22 { get; set; }
    public Day23 day_23 { get; set; }
    public Day25 day_25 { get; set; }
    public Day26 day_26 { get; set; }
    public Day27 day_27 { get; set; }
    public Day29 day_29 { get; set; }
}

public class _50011
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int isInProduction { get; set; }
    public double total_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_overjob_hours { get; set; }
    public int total_days { get; set; }
    public int total_vacation { get; set; }
    public int total_sick { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Sunday { get; set; }
    public int total_work_Saturday { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_Adm { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_1 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_2 { get; set; }
    public int total_shift_3 { get; set; }
    public Day02 day_02 { get; set; }
    public Day03 day_03 { get; set; }
    public Day04 day_04 { get; set; }
    public Day05 day_05 { get; set; }
    public Day08 day_08 { get; set; }
    public Day09 day_09 { get; set; }
    public Day10 day_10 { get; set; }
    public Day11 day_11 { get; set; }
    public Day12 day_12 { get; set; }
    public Day15 day_15 { get; set; }
    public Day16 day_16 { get; set; }
    public Day17 day_17 { get; set; }
    public Day18 day_18 { get; set; }
    public Day19 day_19 { get; set; }
    public Day22 day_22 { get; set; }
    public Day23 day_23 { get; set; }
    public Day24 day_24 { get; set; }
    public Day25 day_25 { get; set; }
    public Day26 day_26 { get; set; }
    public Day27 day_27 { get; set; }
    public Day29 day_29 { get; set; }
}

public class Day02
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day03
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day04
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day05
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day08
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day09
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day10
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day11
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day12
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day13
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day15
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day16
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day17
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day18
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day19
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day22
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day23
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day24
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day25
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day26
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day27
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Day29
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public double hours { get; set; }
    public int shift { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("50010")]
    public _50010 _50010 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("50011")]
    public _50011 _50011 { get; set; }
}
```

p.s. used this for converting: https://json2csharp.com/

p.p.s. I doubt you want it to have this structure.

Comment: I used the same link to convert but I don't like the structure. I want to have list of Root, not one object with many sub objects :(

Comment: Not to mention that those 50010 goes up to 52000. It's ridiculous to create object for each one.

Comment: is it possible to restructure the json ?

Answer (score -3):

I hope I will never need to do this again. But this is how I resolve my issue.

```
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(json).Children();


                foreach(var dt in jsonData)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dt.Path);

                    foreach (var i in dt)
                    {
                        var newSingleEmp = new SingleEmp();

                        newSingleEmp.PersonalId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Path);
                        newSingleEmp.isInProduction = Convert.ToInt32(i["isInProduction"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_hours = Convert.ToDouble(i["total_hours"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_overjob_hours = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_overjob_hours"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_days = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_days"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_vacation = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_vacation"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_sick = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_sick"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_work_Sunday = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_work_Sunday"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_work_Saturday = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_work_Saturday"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_shift_Adm = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_shift_Adm"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_shift_1 = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_shift_1"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_shift_2 = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_shift_2"]);
                        newSingleEmp.total_shift_3 = Convert.ToInt32(i["total_shift_3"]);
                        newSingleEmp.day_01 = new Day01()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_01"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_01"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_01"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_02 = new Day02()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_02"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_02"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_02"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_03 = new Day03()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_03"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_03"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_03"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_04 = new Day04()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_04"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_04"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_04"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_05 = new Day05()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_05"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_05"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_05"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_06 = new Day06()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_06"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_06"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_06"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_07 = new Day07()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_07"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_07"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_07"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_08 = new Day08()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_08"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_08"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_08"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_09 = new Day09()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_09"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_09"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_09"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_10 = new Day10()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_10"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_10"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_10"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_11 = new Day11()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_11"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_11"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_11"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_12 = new Day12()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_12"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_12"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_12"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_13 = new Day13()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_13"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_13"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_13"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_14 = new Day14()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_14"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_14"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_14"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_15 = new Day15()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_15"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_15"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_15"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_16 = new Day16()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_16"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_16"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_16"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_17 = new Day17()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_17"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_17"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_17"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_18 = new Day18()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_18"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_18"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_18"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_19 = new Day19()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_19"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_19"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_19"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_20 = new Day20()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_20"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_20"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_20"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_21 = new Day21()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_21"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_21"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_21"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_22 = new Day22()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_22"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_22"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_22"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_23 = new Day23()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_23"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_23"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_23"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_24 = new Day24()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_24"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_24"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_24"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_25 = new Day25()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_25"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_25"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_25"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_26 = new Day26()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_26"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_26"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_26"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_27 = new Day27()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_27"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_27"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_27"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_28 = new Day28()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_28"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_28"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_28"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_29 = new Day29()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_29"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_29"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_29"]).Item2
                                                        };

                        newSingleEmp.day_30 = new Day30()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_30"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_30"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_30"]).Item2
                                                        };
                        newSingleEmp.day_31 = new Day31()
                                                        {
                                                            comment = GetComment(i["day_31"]).Item1,
                                                            hours = GetHours(i["day_31"]),
                                                            shift = GetComment(i["day_31"]).Item2
                                                        };


                        Console.WriteLine(newSingleEmp);

                    }

                }
```